# AngularJS Update Array Items by a Given Key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm using AngularJS to create a site.

There's my array:

```
$scope.replyList = [
  {
    "id": "85485",
    "reply_content": "aaaaaaa",
    "reply_gender": "1",
    "reply_author": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": "85487",
    "reply_content": "bbbbbbb",
    "reply_gender": "1",
    "reply_author": "Ben"
  },
  {
    "id": "85504",
    "reply_content": "ccccccc",
    "reply_gender": "1",
    "reply_author": "Wang"
  }
]
```

What I want to do is update the item value by a given key `id`.

For example, I'd like to update the content with id `85485`. How can you deal with that?

```
$scope.replyList[{id: 85475}].reply_content = 'dddddd'; /* failed */
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** method to get the array element.

```
$scope.replyList.find(function(v) {
  return v.id == 85475;
}).reply_content = 'dddddd';

// or with ES6 arrow function 

$scope.replyList.find(v => v.id == 85475).reply_content = 'dddddd';
```

---

```js
var replyList = [{
  "id": "85475",
  "reply_content": "aaaaaaa",
  "reply_gender": "1",
  "reply_author": "John"
}, {
  "id": "85487",
  "reply_content": "bbbbbbb",
  "reply_gender": "1",
  "reply_author": "Ben"
}, {
  "id": "85504",
  "reply_content": "ccccccc",
  "reply_gender": "1",
  "reply_author": "Wang"
}];

replyList.find(function(v) {
  return v.id == 85475;
}).reply_content = 'dddddd';

console.log(replyList);
```

---

For older browser [check polyfill option of find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill).

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to update all the element with that particular `id` then use **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** method to iterate. Actually, there is no need of **[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** method since you just want to update the value.

```
$scope.replyList.forEach(function(v) {
   if(v.id == 85475) v.reply_content = 'dddddd';
});
```

---

```js
var replyList = [{
  "id": "85475",
  "reply_content": "aaaaaaa",
  "reply_gender": "1",
  "reply_author": "John"
}, {
  "id": "85487",
  "reply_content": "bbbbbbb",
  "reply_gender": "1",
  "reply_author": "Ben"
}, {
  "id": "85504",
  "reply_content": "ccccccc",
  "reply_gender": "1",
  "reply_author": "Wang"
}];

replyList.forEach(function(v) {
  if (v.id == 85475) v.reply_content = 'dddddd';
});

console.log(replyList);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This code shows an error `undefined is not an object`. What is the question?

Comment: @Benyi :  there is no element with that id

Comment: @Benyi :  to avoid that keep a reference variable like : `var obj = $scope.replyList.find(function(v) {
  return v.id == 85475;
}); obj && obj.reply_content = 'dddddd';`

Comment: Thank you very much. I made a silly mistake. This works fine. It's helpful !

Comment: @Benyi :  glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.filter` method of array and get the first position of the result

```
$scope.replyList.filter(function(item){
  return item.id === '85475';
})[0].reply_content = 'dddddd';
```

If exists more than one result with the given value of key, process them all using the `.map` method.

```
$scope.replyList
  .filter(function(item){
    return item.id === '85475';
  })
  .map(function(item){
     item.reply_content = 'ddddd'
     return item;
   });
```

Take advantage of the javascript functional approach!!

Comment: Thank you very much. This code works fine with AngularJS!

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple for loop to iterate over the array and find the object with the matching id and replace the content.This will work in all browsers.

```
function replace(array, id, content) {
    var len = array.length,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (array[i].id === id) {
            array[i].reply_content = content;
        }
    }
};

replace($scope.replyList, '85485', 'replacedcontent');
```